# Why phpinfo() shows a different version than php -v?

Tags: php, macos, apache

I install php via brew. With brew install PHP. My version of `php-cli` is `7.2`

- But, if I use `phpinfo()` on my server, I get php version 7.1.
- If I use `php -v` in my terminal, I get php version 7.2.

Comment: because php CLI may be different than PHP CGI. PHP GCI is used for web applications, PHP CLI is used for scripts in terminal

Comment: what is your server? default apache from mac or using like MAMP/XAMPP/etc?

Comment: It isn't because of `phpinfo()`. It's because you're using different interpreters.

Comment: How i can update my apache version ? I use apache server, not MAMP etc.. And now i run default apache2 server.

Comment: @voodooSHAA see [How To Change What Version of PHP Apache2 Uses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/149039/how-to-change-what-version-of-php-apache2-uses)

Comment: @Cid i am using mac os

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm adding this *hopefully* extensive answer as part of the **Revival** badge. (Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more)

### TL;DR

`php -v` settings can be different from `phpinfo()` inside your `web-server` due to the running service state of fpm and your webserver. Perhaps you need to restart `php-fpm` and/or your `web-server` (apache, nginx, ..).

### Long version: Command line

Command-line based calls like `php -v` or `php -i` or `php test.php` will read your configuration, options and arguments every time you execute your script within a terminal.

This means if you update php in your operating system then you'll get the most recent version in your terminal session.

**Attention: Depending on your PATH variables you still might get an older version.**

What does this mean? Even if you update your php version on your operating system you might still have an older terminal session which links to an older php-binary.

Here is an example: I am an OSX user and installed php through [brew](https://brew.sh). Currently `php` links to `php@7.3`. Here is my way to validate which versions are running where. For this I'm using [which](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) php.

```
$ which php
/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php
```

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 11:29:42) ( NTS )

// or the equivalent "absolute path" example

$ /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php -v
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 11:29:42) ( NTS )
```

I have multiple php-versions installed on my local system. I can run them all individually. Here is an example:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php -v
PHP 7.2.20 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2019 12:56:54) ( NTS )
```

### Long version: Why is my phpinfo() using the wrong php version?

Since we now have an understanding that we can run multiple and different versions of php on a single operating system, lets dig into our web-server based script which runs `phpinfo()`.

After installing a new php-version you'll have your binaries replaced by new versions. Awesome! but.. how does my running web server get notified about it?

For this I'll refer to the php documentation [Apache 2.x on Unix systems](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) **Point 7**. Also apache allows us to load different modules for PHP.

> Edit your httpd.conf to load the PHP module. [...]
>
> For PHP 7:
>   `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so`
>
> For PHP 5:
>   `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`

Since you are upgrading from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.2 there is probably no change but your webserver is still running the old linked version of php.

In this case a restart of your apache webserver should help so it can pickup the new binaries correctly.

Please let me know if this will help you to solve your issue. For all the other readers: If you think there is something missing OR there is something wrong in my explanation then please let me know with a comment.

Comment: Hello @Christoph, How to load the module if we are to upgrade from PHP 7.1 to PHP 8.0

Comment: @snn Dependng how you defined your `IfModule` e.g. `<IfModule php_module>`. In that case it will be `LoadModule php_module modules/libphp8.0.so`. Can you try this one?

Comment: Hey @Christoph Yes i already tried this by adding - 
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

But while executing PHP file, the code doesn't seem to parse, it's just printing the text as is.
I am trying this on m1 macOS BigSur

Comment: @snn can you check this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-code-shows-in-browser